# How to pick all xml files from folder in c# and parse them

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I faced the problem of getting values from existing XML files into my c# program about a month ago.
I've tried many different answers in stackoverflow but it was not exactly what I needed.
I wanted to share the solution I've found here so it may help others facing a similar problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's not a question. you better post it on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @ZoharPeled he is not asking for a review. He is sharing a solution for a problem.  If he wish he may ask a review of his code, but this isn't his original intention. I think he should ask a question and answer it directly (that's the way for making wiki no?)

Comment: @chillworld I guess you have a point there. still it's not a question so the OP better edit it or move it to a more appropriate web site

Comment: @ZoharPeled I've edited the question and added an answer to it,thx for your comment

Comment: @ElvinNoMatter Accept it as answer too

Comment: @ElvinNoMatter I've retracted my close vote and edited your question. cheers.

Comment: @Shaharyar I'm trying but only thing I see is an alert with this content:

You can accept your own answer in 2 days

Comment: Sorry I forgot this rule http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already resolved this problem but want to share this solution with you.

**Note:** this only applicable for xml files with the same content.

Let me show you how I fixed it:

**First step:** 
I've created a class with the xml structure exactly as in my xml file

```
[XmlRoot("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("Msg")]
    public Msg Msgs { get; set; }
}


public class Msg
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Rows")]
    public Rows RowsObj { get; set; }
}
public class Rows
{

    [XmlElement("Row")]
    public List<Row> RowsList { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string InvoiceCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ServiceCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string BranchID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string AbonCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string PaymentDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ReceiptNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string PaymentSite { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string PaymentInstrument { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string BankHeadOfficeCode { get; set; }
}
```

This is my .xml file structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Header/>
  <Msg>
    <Type>INVOICE_PAY_APUS</Type>
    <UserID>888888</UserID>
    <SerialNumber>8210089</SerialNumber>
    <DateTime>2015-04-15T15:20:17</DateTime>
    <Rows>
        <Row>
            <InvoiceCode>1414016335DR</InvoiceCode>
            <BranchID>981008</BranchID>
            <AbonCode>1414016335</AbonCode>
            <Amount>80.00</Amount>
            <PaymentDate>2015-04-15T15:20:03</PaymentDate>
            <ReceiptNumber>95037101</ReceiptNumber>
            <PaymentSite>GPP</PaymentSite>
            <PaymentInstrument>4</PaymentInstrument>
            <BankHeadOfficeCode>qwerty</BankHeadOfficeCode>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <InvoiceCode>1414016335XH</InvoiceCode>
            <BranchID>981005</BranchID>
            <AbonCode>1414016335</AbonCode>
            <Amount>34.00</Amount>
            <PaymentDate>2015-04-15T15:20:03</PaymentDate>
            <ReceiptNumber>95037103</ReceiptNumber>
            <PaymentInstrument>4</PaymentInstrument>
            <PaymentSite>GPP</PaymentSite>
            <BankHeadOfficeCode>AZRTAZ22</BankHeadOfficeCode>
        </Row>
    </Rows>
  </Msg>
</Data>
```

As you can see, I have a root element called **Data** and **Msg** element under **Data** and etc.

**Second Step:**

In my main class of console application I'm trying to reach the folder where my xml files are placed and after it I'm reading the data from xml and parsing it to my object.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        string mainPath = "C:\\xmlTest"; //folder with my xml files goes here, it's optional, you can change it to whatever you want
        Data data = new Data();

        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mainPath, "*.xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file);

            data = (Data)mySerializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
            streamReader.Close();
            List<Row> rows = data.Msgs.RowsObj.RowsList;

            foreach (var row in rows)
                    {
                        //do stuff here
                        //example: string paymentType = row.InvoiceCode.Substring(row.InvoiceCode.Length - 2);
                    }



        }
    }
}
```

That's it, hope it will help you guys.